# Router forces browser to use older, presumably cached, webfiles

Tags: router, cache, cloudflare

We are trouble shooting website where we deploy a new version but our Computer browser still pulls the older pages. When we disconnect from the router (WiFi) and connect to a hotspot (mobile phone/data), the browser correctly pulls the new pages. If we switch back to the router (WiFi), the problem returns. We have tried trouble shooting

- We have confirmed the new files were successfully deployed
- We have confirmed the old files are being downloaded (by looking at Inspect > Sources)
- Disabling cache in Inspect>Network
- Clearing all browser cache
- Purging cache on Cloudflare
- Setting Cloudflare Cache to Developer Mode
- Using different browsers (Chrome and Brave)
- Using different computers (both connected to same WiFi)

We have tried simple tests on computers in different locations (different countries). One test simply loaded the old page. The second test loaded the new page. We can't really draw any conclusions from this test.

The web pages are static HTML and JS files only.

Anyone know what the possible source for this bizarre behavior could be?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? Are you hitting the same domain fromtej same browser when testing from WiFi and not?

Comment: Yes, HTTPS. Hitting exact same domain from exact same browser (pressing CTRL+R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that on Cloudflare we have two entries for the same URL (eg. [www.dev.example.com](http://www.dev.example.com) -> 10.0.0.1 and [www.dev.example.com](http://www.dev.example.com) -> 99.99.99.99). Once we removed one of those the problem went away.